# How to change limit of this integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let

$ I$ = $$\int_0^{a}\int_0^{a-x}\left(f(x,y)\right)dydx$$ then I need to find the new integral by changing the variables

$x+y = u$ and $xy =v$, Now for u I can easily find the limits as they vary from 0 to $a$ but I am little confused about changing limits of $v$

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: The transformation $\Phi := (x, y) \mapsto (u, v)$ is not bijective on the domain of integration, or even its interior, as (even the interior of) $D$ contains distinct points that map to the same pair $(u, v)$, for example, $(\frac{a}{4}, \frac{a}{2})$ and $(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{a}{4})$, so the coordinate transformation cannot be used without some adjustments. (Indeed, $f$ is not a function of $u, v$ unless $f(x, y) = f(y, x)$.)

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$g_{1, 2}(u, v) = \frac {u \pm \sqrt {u^2 - 4 v}} 2.$$
If $y < x$, then, since $g_2 < g_1$, we have $(x, y) = (g_1(u, v), g_2(u, v))$. The mapping $F = (x, y) \mapsto (x + y, x y)$ is a diffeomorphism between $\{(x, y): y < x \}$ and $D = \{(u, v): v < u^2/4\}$ and also between $\{(x, y): y > x \}$ and $D$.

Assume $a > 0$ and consider the parts of the integration domain where $y < x$ and where $y > x$. The line $x = 0$ is mapped to itself by $F$ and the line $y = a - x$ is mapped to the ray from $(a, a^2/4)$ to $(a, -\infty)$. We get a triangular domain in $D$ bounded by two straight lines. Therefore
$$\int_0^a \int_0^{a - x} f(x, y) dy dx = \\
\int_0^a \int_0^{u^2/4} \frac
 {f(g_1(u, v), g_2(u, v)) + f(g_2(u, v), g_1(u, v))}
 {\sqrt {u^2 - 4 v \,}} dv du.$$